# Postfix Sendonly Multiple Domains - smtp Auth for each domain?

Tags: postfix, opendkim

My title pretty much sums it up
I have recently setup a sendonly postfix server
i used this guide
https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfix-send-only-multiple-domains-ubuntu#generate-dkim-keypair
It works as expected.

The purpose of this server is to be used by our hosted websites to send the website mail.
My server sends successfully from the three test domains i have used

I would like to lock down the ability to send from any particular domain with smtp auth

So a username and password for each domain i have setup.

Is this possible?
any guidance is appreciated

Comment: What i have ended up doing.

I setup and Cyrus SASL.
And created username and passwords inthe format of user@domian to try differentiate them.

But they are global user and pass 
and can send from any domain .

Answer (score 0):

What i have ended up doing.

I setup Cyrus SASL.
And created username and passwords in the format of user@domian to try differentiate them.

But they are global user and pass
and can send from any domain.
This solution works in the fact that we now have smtp auth working
but I'd still like to find a way to associate the logins with domains